# CannotLoadBeanClassException in spring amqp

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am very new to spring amqp. I am trying to run a sample application, and the sender code is running successfully but the listener code is throwing an error. Please help.
Please find the codes in the link below - 
https://www.journaldev.com/11713/spring-amqp-rabbitmq-example

The error thrown -

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.tp.spring.amqp.rabbit.SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener] for bean with name 'asyncListener' defined in class path resource [springamqp-rabbt-listener-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tp.spring.amqp.rabbit.SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener

The error I am getting now when I run the SpringAMQPRabbitListenerContainer.java, is as shown below-

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'myListenerContainer'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on
>   listener startup  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$1(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:339)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at
>   com.tp.spring_amqp_rabbitmq.SpringAMQPRabbitListenerContainer.main(SpringAMQPRabbitListenerContainer.java:9)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal
>   exception on listener startup     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:360)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:167)
>     ... 9 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.FatalListenerStartupException:
>   Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or
>   the broker will not allow us to use it.   at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:516)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:996)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclarePassive(AutorecoveringChannel.java:364)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:348)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:213)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException:
>   channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404,
>   reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'tpQueue' in vhost '/', class-id=50,
>   method-id=10)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException:
>   channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404,
>   reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'tpQueue' in vhost '/', class-id=50,
>   method-id=10)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:509)    at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:340)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:162)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:109)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581)
>     ... 1 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be sure that the class `com.tp.spring.amqp.rabbit.SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener` is on your classpath.

I understand that XML config my mislead, but without that class in the mentioned `com.tp.spring.amqp.rabbit` package it really isn't going to work.

Plus pay attention how that class has a type in the `Async` part.

Comment: Thank you so much. The class path wasnt given correctly.That solved my problem

Comment: But now when I run SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener.java, I get an error saying -

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'myListenerContainer'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: Fatal exception on listener startup

Comment: Could you please help

Comment: I think there is something else in the logs, please, share it with an edit to your question. That too hard to read stack traces from comments here

Comment: Sorry, please find the latest stack now,

Comment: OK. Does it say anything to you: `(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'tpQueue' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10) ` ?

Comment: Yes..is it because the queue name is not given in the tag - <rabbit : queue id ="tpQueue">??